# MeiliSearch for PDF and Docx files

Tags: indexing, meilisearch

Is it possible to use Meilisearch to search contents of PDF and DOCX files? If yes What is the process of indexing and searching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible to index PDF or DOCS files with MeiliSearch, you have to extract the text from your file and push the content into MeiliSearch. The current content types accepted are JSON, CSV, and NDJSON.

Here you can find a discussion where a user explains his approach: https://github.com/meilisearch/product/discussions/164